# How to solve an unexpected token?

Tags: jsx, token, unexpected-token

I don't know why I have a problem with 'item'. I don't understand what it is about and how I can solve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXfT1.jpg)

I tried with (_item), it doesn't work. I also tried to write // @ts-ignore in the previous line of code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), you could have posted the code as TEXT, and not as an image...

Comment: You seem to follow a different syntax than the examples given here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html   (But I am not developing in Rust, so I cannot tell which is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `li` goes inside the braces of `map` function. Changing your code to something like this will fix the issue.

```js
['home','about','work'].map((item) =>
  <li>{item}</li>
);
```

For more details, https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Glad it helped. :) Consider marking this as correct answer so that this may help others with the same issue.